# pathname asterisk expansion and making new files

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I had directories such as 1 2 3 in directory called a .I wanted to create files 1/file.txt, 2/file.txt, 3/file.txt this way 
`$> a/*/file.txt`
but failed. I thought that * would be expanded to 1, 2 and 3.
Can you explan what happened here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think shell expansion with `*` will work only if the files already exist. Also, I don't think you can specify multiple targets with `>` redirection

If you know all the directory names under `a`, then you can use brace expansion (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BraceExpansion for more details)

```
$ # echo is here used to show how the shell would expand the braces
$ echo a/{1,2,3}/file.txt
a/1/file.txt a/2/file.txt a/3/file.txt
$ # touch command will create an empty file if it doesn't already exist
$ touch a/{1,2,3}/file.txt
```

If you don't know all the directory names, then you can use a loop instead

```
$ for d in a/*; do touch "$d"/file.txt; done
```